# PHP Works in PHP Fiddle but not in Browser

Tags: javascript, php, json, facebook-graph-api, curl

My PHP works in my [PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/p7c-g64) but not when I copy it exactly into Sublime 2, save it as a .php document, upload it to my server [here on my website](http://www.joshiefishbein.com/fi/namebook4.php).  The problem I think exists in the JSON, it's not decoding the information right and is always "Invalid ID", but if you run in the Fiddle it always gives at least 3-4 correct names.  But I never get any names when in any of the browsers like Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.  Why could this be?

```
<?php
function gen_pix($min, $max, $quantity) {
$numbers = range($min, $max);
shuffle($numbers);
$x_arr = array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
foreach ($x_arr as $key => $value) {
    $username = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $value . "/";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($username), true);
    if (!isset($json['name'])) {
        echo "Invalid ID<br />";
    }
    else {
        echo $json["name"]. '<br />';
    } 
  }
}

$x = 337800042;
$y = 337800382;
$z = 50;

gen_pix($x,$y,$z);  
?>
```

UPDATE: with error reporting turned on.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /hermes/bosoraweb186/b1303/ipg.joshiefishbeincom/fi/namebook4.php on line 11
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/337800127/): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /hermes/bosoraweb186/b1303/ipg.joshiefishbeincom/fi/namebook4.php on line 11
```

UPDATE 2: now using cURL

This is my new code:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors",1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function gen_pix($min, $max, $quantity) {
$numbers = range($min, $max);
shuffle($numbers);
$x_arr = array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
foreach ($x_arr as $key => $value) {
    $username = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $value . "/";

    if (!function_exists("curl_init")){
       die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $username); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);  // 60 seconds timeout
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 

    if (!isset($json['name'])) {
        print("error");
    }
    else {
        print($json["name"]). '<br />';
    } 
  }
}

$x = 337800042;
$y = 337800382;
$z = 10;

gen_pix($x,$y,$z);  
?>
```

Now it gives me just "H" for each line.  So I switched out the `else` to `print_r($json);` to see what the array looked like and this is what I got:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 ETag: "f07656bdb736f1a09e1aa2bb16ecce2b3b1f483e" Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT Pragma: no-cache X-FB-Rev: 1135358 X-FB-Debug: Ha05GqDUPxzl4bA3x9xreOZCveNsf8QiOGExgPU9p6c= Date: Tue, 25 Feb 2014 05:12:49 GMT Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 148 {"id":"337800051","name":"Irem Muftuoglu","first_name":"Irem","last_name":"Muftuoglu","gender":"female","locale":"nb_NO","username":"iremmuftuoglu"}
```

Comment: Works for me too, except it gets a lot of `warnings`.. Is that you're talking about?

Comment: @vlzvl where does it work for you?  In the Fiddle?  In a browser?  I get no warnings?  What are your warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm too no familiar with the `Graph API`, but i get this:
Calling this from *Fiddle* **and** my *local server's .php*, i get:

```
<?php
function gen_pix($min, $max, $quantity) {
$numbers = range($min, $max);
shuffle($numbers);
$x_arr = array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
foreach ($x_arr as $key => $value) {
   $username = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $value . "/";
      $data = file_get_contents($username);

      // if ($data===FALSE) { continue; }

      $json = json_decode($data, true);

      if (!isset($json['name'])) {
         echo "Invalid ID<br />";
      }
      else {
         echo $json["name"]. '<br />';
      } 
   }
}

$x = 337800042;
$y = 337800382;
$z = 50;

gen_pix($x,$y,$z);  
?>
```

I have put the line `if ($data===FALSE) { continue; }` myself, although it doesnt solve much. It seems **file_get_contents** requests works well, but sometimes (well, in most of the times) returns an error JSON like this:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

although you would be able to handle that too and print "Invalid ID".
My first thought is if your server supports `file_get_contents` at all, is your error_reporting on?

```
ini_set("display_errors",1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
...
if (function_exists("file_get_contents")) {
   file_get_contents("...")
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just to verify the max execution time..
Can you verify somehow if the call takes longer than this:

```
echo ini_get("max_execution_time");
```

**EDIT 2:**

So [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) is disabled, thus you cannot use **file_get_contents** at all, or enabling **allow_url_fopen**.
You may want to use a [cURL](https://php.net/curl) or [fsockopen](http://php.net/fsockopen), here's a simple code (also, they may be disabled as well)

```
if (!function_exists("curl_init")){
   echo "Sorry cURL is not supported either!";
}
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "THE_URL"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);  // 60 seconds timeout
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**EDIT 3:**

My bad, just remove the headers from the return:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```

also, request without SSL

```
$username = "http://graph.facebook.com/" . $value . "/";
```

Lastly, you still need to decode the JSON:

```
$json = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: I just checked this.  With just the code at the very bottom to see if `file_get_contents` exists and it does.  No errors.

Comment: You get blank? Also, these requests are `dragging in time`. Maybe the max execution time is consumed also? (check edit).

Comment: It doesn't time out, it immediately renders all 50 entries to be invalid.  I have even adjusted it to 10 and 5 and 1, still invalid.

Comment: How's that possible? im taking nearly 40 seconds to call all requests :) It seems you need to `print_r($json)` to see what it has.. It seems there are no requests at all but you get no error with error reporting on.

Comment: Wait, my bad, errors weren't actually on.  I got errors.  Check above in original post.

Comment: We're getting closer, new issue from cURL response but I can see that it actually makes a legitimate request.  Do you know what the above problem is?

Comment: Phew, i hope it's ok now, i'm able to get the JSON i want with cURL, i hope you too

Comment: WOW. It finally works as I want it to.  Thank you so much for sticking in there!!